# PIR Sensor Counter

Tags: python, script, motion

Hey guys I'm trying to create a simple script that essentially counts the amount of people that reside within a room, by having an entry sensor and exit sensor and tells you how many are within the room. Here is the script i have written so far but am getting an error "TypeEROR: Enter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'MOTION2' ".

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
MOTION1 = 4
MOTION2 = 23
GPIO.setup(MOTION1, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(MOTION2, GPIO.IN)

counts = 0
exits = 0
state = 0


#functions    
def counter():
    global counts
    counts += 1
    counts + state                            
    print('Residents: ', state)


def exiter():
    global exits
    exits = counts - 1                                               
    exits + state
    print('Residents ', state)

def ENTER(MOTION1, MOTION2): 
    while True:
       if (GPIO.input(MOTION1)== GPIO.HIGH):
          print ('Entered Building')
          time.sleep(2)
          counter()
       elif (GPIO.input(MOTION2)== GPIO.HIGH):
           print ('Exited Building')
           time.sleep(2)
           exiter()

      
print ('PIR Module Test (CTRL+C to exit)')
time.sleep(2)
print ('Ready')

try:
    GPIO.add_event_detect(MOTION1, GPIO.RISING, callback=ENTER)
    while 1:
          time.sleep(100)
    
except KeyboardInterrupt:
     print (' Quit')
     GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: It is NONSENSE having a callback with an infinite loop. You can't just invent functions and expect them to work. Try reading the documentation https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/

Comment: @Milliways, thanks for the response but im still unsure how i would go about doing the code

Comment: Did you actually read the linked documentation? There is an example there with 2 callbacks (although I would use https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_input.html?highlight=motion#gpiozero.MotionSensor.motion_detected but frankly I think your basic premise is flawed, motion sensors are wide area devices.

Comment: This is really just a how do I write a program question.  Nothing much to do with the Pi.